# How to access an attribute / method of a stateful widget from outside?

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to access the method setBlockText() inside the _InnerBlockState class from outside to change the label of the Text Widget e.g. OuterBlock.setInnerBlockLabel(). Is this even possible? A small example is just provided below.

```
class OuterBlock {

    Widget column;
    Widget innerBlock;

    OuterBlock() {
      innerBlock = new InnerBlock();
      initColumn();
    }

    initColumn() {
      column = new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
         innerBlock
      ] 
    }

   setInnerBlockLabel() {
      // TODO set the text/ label from the Text Widget of the innerBlock
   }
}

class InnerBlock extends StatefulWidget {

   @override
   State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
     return _InnerBlockState();
   }
}

class _InnerBlockState extends State<InnerBlock> {

   String label = '';

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        child: Text(label)
      );
   }

   void setBlockText(String label) {
      this.label= label;
   }
}
```

Comment: if you want to change label from any class you must use `InheritedModel` but if the parent `InnerBlock ` is `StatefulWidget ` you can define the final attribute in `InnerBlock`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly then you have two widgets. Lets call them `Widget A` and `Widget B`.

`Widget B` has a text variable and is USED by `Widget A`. You want to change the text variable in `Widget A`.

My solution: Pass a variable to  `Widget B`.

Code:

```
// shouldn't your OuterBlock be a widget?
class OuterBlock {
  Widget column;
  Widget innerBlock;
  String yourLabel;

  OuterBlock() {
    innerBlock = new InnerBlock(textVariable: yourLabel);
    initColumn();
  }

  initColumn() {
    column = new Column(children: <Widget>[innerBlock]);
  }

  setInnerBlockLabel() {
    yourLabel = "fancy Label"; // your fancy business logic :P
  }
}

class InnerBlock extends StatefulWidget {
  final String textVariable;

  InnerBlock({Key key, this.textVariable}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _InnerBlockState();
  }
}

class _InnerBlockState extends State<InnerBlock> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Text(widget.textVariable));
  }
}
```

Yours Glup3